# Timezone is not set on a dayjs object when created

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, dayjs

I have a Karma test in a web application. In the test, I had created a `dayjs` date. Sometimes when I create the dayjs object, the time zone is not set. This problem occurs when I run all test in the project.

This is a simplified version of the test.

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import DayJSUtc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import DayJSTimezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'
dayjs.extend(DayJSUtc)
dayjs.extend(DayJSTimezone)

describe('dayjs helper', () => {

    const timezone: string = 'Europe/Stockholm';

    describe('addDays', () => {
            it('Subtract 1 day over transaction to summmer time', async () => {
                const date = dayjs('2023-10-30').tz(timezone,  true);

                expect(date["$x"]["$timezone"]).toEqual(timezone);
            });
        });
});
```

When I debugged the test this is how the date should look like
[image: how date looks like in debug]

And this is how it looks when the timezone is not set
[image: how it looks like when timezone is not set]